# Mgo wrong type for field

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am trying to do a bulk upsert with the mgo library. I was reading the [documentation](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Bulk.Upsert) regarding bulk upserts since this is the first time I've ever used MongoDB, and it looks like I have to provide pairs of documents to update.

In my function, I'm performing a find all query, then using the results from the query to use as the existing part of the pair for the `bulk.Upsert()` operation. I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it, but I have to do upserts on ~65k documents at a time.

Here are the type structs, and the worker pool function which reads from a channel to perform the aforementioned MongoDB operations.

```
// types from my project's `lib` package.
type Auctions struct {
    Auc          int `json:"auc" bson:"_id"`
    Item         int `json:"item" bson:"item"`
    Owner        string `json:"owner" bson:"owner"`
    OwnerRealm   string `json:"ownerRealm" bson:"ownerRealm"`
    Bid          int `json:"bid" bson:"bid"`
    Buyout       int `json:"buyout" bson:"buyout"`
    Quantity     int `json:"quantity" bson:"quantity"`
    TimeLeft     string `json:"timeLeft" bson:"timeLeft"`
    Rand         int `json:"rand" bson:"rand"`
    Seed         int `json:"seed" bson:"seed"`
    Context      int `json:"context" bson:"context"`
    BonusLists   []struct {
        BonusListID int `json:"bonusListId" bson:"bonusListId"`
    } `json:"bonusLists,omitempty" bson:"bonusLists,omitempty"`
    Modifiers    []struct {
        Type  int `json:"type" bson:"type"`
        Value int `json:"value" bson:"value"`
    } `json:"modifiers,omitempty" bson:"modifiers,omitempty"`
    PetSpeciesID int `json:"petSpeciesId,omitempty" bson:"petSpeciesId,omitempty"`
    PetBreedID   int `json:"petBreedId,omitempty" bson:"petBreedId,omitempty"`
    PetLevel     int `json:"petLevel,omitempty" bson:"petLevel,omitempty"`
    PetQualityID int `json:"petQualityId,omitempty" bson:"petQualityId,omitempty"`
}

type AuctionResponse struct {
    Realms   []struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
        Slug string `json:"slug"`
    } `json:"realms"`
    Auctions []Auctions `json:"auctions"`
}

func (b *Blizzard) RealmAuctionGrabber(realms chan string, db *mgo.Database, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := range realms {
        NewReq, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("%s/auction/data/%s", b.Url, i), nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Cannot create new request for realm %s: %s", i, err)
        }

        // Update the request with the default parameters and grab the files links.
        Request := PopulateDefaultParams(NewReq)
        log.Debugf("downloading %s auction locations.", i)
        Response, err := b.Client.Do(Request)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error request realm auction data: %s\n", err)
        }
        defer Response.Body.Close()

        Body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(Response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error parsing request body: %s\n", err)
        }

        var AuctionResp lib.AuctionAPI
        err = json.Unmarshal(Body, &AuctionResp)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error marshalling auction repsonse body: %s\n", err)
        }

        for _, x := range AuctionResp.Files {
            NewDataReq, err := http.NewRequest("GET", x.URL, nil)
            if err != nil {
                log.Error(err)
            }

            AuctionResponse, err := b.Client.Do(NewDataReq)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error request realm auction data: %s\n", err)
            }
            defer Response.Body.Close()

            AuctionBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(AuctionResponse.Body)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error parsing request body: %s\n", err)
            }

            var AuctionData lib.AuctionResponse
            err = json.Unmarshal(AuctionBody, &AuctionData)

            // grab all the current records, then perform an Upsert!
            var existing []lib.Auctions
            col := db.C(i)
            err = col.Find(nil).All(&existing)
            if err != nil {
                log.Error(err)
            }

            log.Infof("performing bulk upsert for %s", i)

            auctionData, err := bson.Marshal(AuctionData.Auctions)
            if err != nil {
                log.Error("error marshalling bson: %s", err)
            }

            existingData, _ := bson.Marshal(existing)
            bulk := db.C(i).Bulk()
            bulk.Upsert(existingData, auctionData)
            _, err = bulk.Run()
            if err != nil {
                log.Error("error performing upsert! error: ", err)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `bulk.Upsert(existingData,auctionData)`, things are fine. However, when I call `bulk.Run()`, I'm getting this logged error message:

```
{"level":"error","msg":"error performing upsert! error: wrong type for 'q' field, expected object, found q: BinData(0, 0500000000)","time":"2016-07-09T16:53:45-07:00"}
```

I'm assuming this is related to how I'm doing the BSON tagging in the `Auction` struct, but I'm not sure because this is the first time I've worked with MongoDB. Right now there are no collections in the database,

Is the error message related to the BSON tagging, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is still actual. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "log"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type Auctions struct {
    Auc   int `json:"auc" bson:"_id"`
    Owner string `json:"owner" bson:"owner"`
}

type AuctionResponse struct {
    Auctions []Auctions `json:"auctions"`
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/aucs")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    db := session.DB("aucs")

    var AuctionData AuctionResponse
    AuctionBody, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("auctions.json")
    err = json.Unmarshal(AuctionBody, &AuctionData)

    log.Println("performing bulk upsert for %s", "realm")

    bulk := db.C("realm").Bulk()
    for _, auc := range AuctionData.Auctions {
        bulk.Upsert(bson.M{"_id": auc.Auc}, auc)
    }
    _, err = bulk.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic("error performing upsert! error: ", err)
    }
}
```

There are some changes that I've made to check if I was right on real data but I hope it's not hard to understand what's going on. Now let me explain a bit Mongo's part.

1. You don't need to get `existing` documents. That would be strange to request all existing documents before updating or inserting them especially on huge databases.
2. `mgo`'s `upsert` function requires two parameters:

   - `selector` document (I prefer to think about it as about `WHERE` condition in terms of SQL)
   - `document` that you actually have and that will be inserted into DB if selector query fails
3. In case of bulk `upsert` there is unlimited amount of `selector - document` pairs available to push in one request like `bulk.Upsert(sel1, doc1, sel2, doc2, sel3, doc3)` but in your case there is no point to use this feature.
4. `upsert` affect only single document so even if you `selector` fits multiple documents only first will be updated. In other words, `upsert` is more similar to MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` than to  `UPDATE ... WHERE`. In your case (with unique auction's IDs) single `upsert` looks like MySQL query:

   ```
   INSERT INTO realm (auc, owner) VALUES ('1', 'Hogger') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE owner = 'Hogger';
   ```
5. With `bulk` we can just make multiple upserts in the loop and then run them at once.

Comment: Ah, I see how it works, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a maximum batch size error, though. I'm doing `bulk.Upsert()` in batches of 100, then calling `bulk.Run()` to push those upserts. that should be the proper way to work around that, correct?

Comment: @mynameismevin yes, your way is right. Also, [according to `mgo` issue](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/issues/288) limit is 1000 entries per batch so you should be able to increase the number of auctions per batch.